# Not uploading extension in marketplace and redirecting it to another website: Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, upload, marketplace

The Magento Connect, which has now been closed, could be used to redirect the users to the developer's site from where the extension could be purchased.

Now, with the arrival of Magento Marketplace is there any way to do the same? I understand that the marketplace is reviewing each of the extensions which is actually required to ensure quality, but what if I do not want to upload my extension to the marketplace and want to redirect the users to my corresponding website through which they can get the module.

Is that possible to do with the marketplace?
Please, can anyone help?